# Find Palindrome numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to find the Palindrome numbers between 0 & a given input. There is some error in the code. I think the problem is with the logic.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the limit to check the no of Palindrome ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no = input.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j <= no; j++) {
            if (number(j)) ;
            ++count;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static boolean number(int num) {


        int i = num;
        int reverse = 0;
        while (i != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + i % 10;
            i = i / 10;
        }


        if (num == reverse) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please list the error.

Answer (score 2):

`if` statement with semicolon at the end is considered to be a null statement. So if you remove `;` from the end of if condition, you should be good to get palindrome count between 0 and n. Also note integer max range in Java is 2,147,483,647 which means if you enter that as `n` value, it would overflow and hence you should choose type of `j` as long.

```
if(number(j));
             ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It really helps me.

Comment: @wicky if you feel this has helped, then click on the tick below number of votes, so it would help others in future.

Comment: Now long okay, is but will overflow with any number larger than 9.223372e+18. If you really want crazy large numbers you should use the BigInteger class.

Comment: OP is expecting integer and hence input would never overflow if he uses long instead. See his code for e.g. `int no = input.nextInt();`